# What does "a" and "the" mean before "Billlion" in these contexts?

Tags: meaning, grammar, grammaticality

I have read two examples about "Billion" word and I got confused with why are existences "a" and " the" in these context. Is it mentioned "definite" and "indefinite" meaing ? I usually see one billion, a million,2 million also ...

Examples-

1. The Clinton administration last winter assembled **the** $50 billion emergency bailout package to ease a financial crisis in Mexico.( From Cambridge dictonary )
2. It is estimated that UK business could save **a** further $3 billion if they made the effort. (From my book)

Comment: It was the package and an amount.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think of them for what they are - the **definite** and the **indefinite** articles.

If the amount concerned is a definite one that has previously been announced then use ***the***, e.g. *the money I promised to send you at Easter*.

If the money concerned is just some future possibility, which may or may not arise then it is correct to speak of - ***a*** possible further amount in July.

Answer (score 0):

In your first example there is emphasis on "the" $50 million package as that emphasized amount saved them from a crisis.

In the second, there is a possibility of saving another $3 billion building it over another few billions. That means "a few billions" (here $3 billion) were further added.